Find $g(a):=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^n(1-\frac{x}{n})^ne^{ax}dx$
Let $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}, \mu) $ be a measure space of Borel sets with Lebesgue measure on the real line. For $a\in\mathbb{R}$, find
$$
g(a):=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^n\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^ne^{ax}dx
$$

Let $y=1-\frac{x}{n}$. Then
$$
g(a)=\int_0^1 ny^ne^{an(1-y)}dy
$$
Clearly, we have $|ny^ne^{an(1-y)}|\le ne^{ay(1-y)}$ and $ne^{an(1-y)}\in L_1[0,1]$ because
$$
\int_0^1ne^{an(1-y)}dy=-a^{-1}e^{an}[e^{-an}-1]<\infty.
$$
By dominated convergence theorem,
$$
g(a)=\int_0^1\lim_{n\to\infty}  ny^ne^{an(1-y)}dy
$$
So $\lim_{n\to\infty}  ny^ne^{an(1-y)}=0$ if $a<0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}  ny^ne^{an(1-y)}=1$ if $a\ge 0$.
I got $g(a)=\infty $ if $a\ge 0$ and $g(a)=0$ if $a<0$.
However, the answer should be $g(a)=\infty $ if $a\ge 1$ and $g(a)=0$ if $a<1$. Where am I wrong?

Based on comment suggested, I still want to ask for $a\ge 1$, we do not have the dominated function. So how do we show that the $g(a)=\infty$ for $a\ge 1$?

The dominationg function in the DCT must not depend on $n$. (Besides, there are small typos : $e^{ay(1-y)}$ instead of $e^{an(1-y)}$, three times.)

@AnneBauval Not yet. I know that we can apply DCT. But I want to ask if I change variable how do we find the dominated function?

@AnneBauval Also, that answer only talk about $a<1$. But I also want to know how to show this integral is infinity for $a\ge 1$.

Your change of variable is not a good idea. Apply the DCT directly like here.

By the MCT, $g(a)=\int_0^\infty e^{(a-1)x}dx$, which is $\infty$ if $a\ge1$, and $\frac1{1-a}$ if $a<1$ (not $g(a)=0$ as you claimed the answer "should be").

Fix $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and define $f_{n}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
by $f_{n}(x)=1_{[0,n]}(x)(1-\frac{x}{n})^{n}e^{ax}$. Clearly $f_{n}$
is non-negative. If $a\geq1$, by Fatou's lemma, we have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int f_{n} & \geq & \int\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_{n}\\
 & = & \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{(a-1)x}dx\\
 & = & \infty.
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int f_{n}$ exists and equals
to $\infty$.
Consider the case that $a<1$. We go to show that $|f_{n}(x)|\leq1_{[0,\infty)}(x)e^{(a-1)x}$
for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Fix $n\in\mathbb{N}$
and define $\phi:[0,n]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $\phi(x)=e^{x}(1-\frac{x}{n})^{n}$.
We have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\phi'(x) & = & -e^{x}\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n-1}\frac{x}{n}\\
 & < & 0
\end{eqnarray*}
for $x\in(0,n)$. Therefore, $\phi$ is strictly decreasing on $[0,n]$.
In particular, $\phi(x)\leq\phi(0)=1$. That is, $(1-\frac{x}{n})^{n}\leq e^{-x}$
for all $x\in[0,n]$. Now, it is clear that for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$
and $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $|f_{n}(x)|\leq1_{[0,\infty)}(x)e^{(a-1)x}$.
Since $x\mapsto1_{[0,\infty)}(x)e^{(a-1)x}$ is integrable, by Lebesgue
Dominated Convergence Theorem, we have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
g(a) & = & \int_{\mathbb{R}}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_{n}(x)dx\\
 & = & \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{(a-1)x}dx\\
 & = & \frac{1}{1-a}.
\end{eqnarray*}
